# Jquery/CSS IE6 issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

This is a very interesting problem. Basically I'm adding a few li tags dynamcially:

```
var fileList =  $("#openWin ul");

for (var i = 0; i<20; i++){
  fileList.append("<li>"+i+"<\/li>");
}
```

I have some css for my li tags:

```
li{
  list-style : none;
  font-size : 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding : 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-bottom : 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-family : Georgia, serif;
  background-color : white;
  cursor : pointer;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work in IE6. The first few li tags don't appear to have the css fully applied to them:

[image]

[Here is a link to the live file.](http://mtcanvas.com/questions/liveli.html) I tried setting up a jsFiddle and jsBin for this but neither of those sites seem to function properly in ie6.

Strangely if I add some events to the li tags, the same issue arises. Adding this code:

```
 $("#openWin li").live('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).css({"background-color": "#ededed"});
 }).live("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).css({"background-color": "white"});
 });
```

Works but the first few li tags act strangely. I'm going to keep working on this, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for a second there the link was broken... fixed it

Comment: I recommend this in the mouseout handler: `$(this).removeAttr("style")`

Comment: I'll give that a try... thinking of just replacing these with divs and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a hasLayout issue - try adding `zoom:1` to your li styles. Another option is adding a space to the text you are appending as below:

```
fileList.append(" <li>"+i+"<\/li>");
```

Comment: very cool. adding zoom fixed it :) Could you explain why you think that is?

Comment: adding zoom created a 1px space between all li tags so I decided to go with using divs... very strange stuff. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Zevan: Updating your `li` CSS from `margin: 0;` to `margin: 0 0 -1px 0;` should take care of that, but which other events were you using that didn't work with `position: relative` commented out?

Comment: @Zevan: difficult to explain in brief; effectively IE can't identify the boundaries of these elements. Here is a good resource: http://haslayout.net/haslayout

Comment: cool. I'll try that with the li css. Will also look at that link

Answer (score 1):

From the image it looks like the CSS works except for the border-bottom.
Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i<20; i++){
  fileList.append("<li style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;\">"+i+"<\/li>");
}
```

Comment: thanks, that will work. Doesn't solve the event problem though.

Answer (score 1):

@Zevan: Comment out `position: relative;` in your `#files` CSS. This should fix the issue.

```
#files {
    background-color: white;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 230px;
}
```

Comment: As for the "why", chalk it up to yet another IE6 bug; it looks very similar to the IE6 "Peekaboo" bug -- http://positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html, though it's not because you're not using `float` anywhere.

Comment: interesting that fixes the css. For some reason none of the events work after that. I replaced the ul/li stuff with divs and it fixes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the loop:

```
$("<li>").text(i).appendTo(fileList);
```